# How to know what image is used when looking at the webpage

Tags: image

There is a facebook logo in the frontend design of my site above the header. I want to replace the it with a different colour facebook image. All i did was go to "skin/frontend/default/template_name/images/" and replace the old image with the new one with the same name. But still, the old image is displayed. Please help?????

Answer (score 1):

Rather simple:

1. make a right click on a image and open image in new tab or inspect the source adress of this image
2. replace the image on the url that it is really displayed
3. clear your browser cache if the image still does not change

Comment: http://**********.com/skin/frontend/default/*****/images/fb_green.png this is the source address. I replaced the fb_green.png with the new image of the same name. Still, the old fb_green is displayed.....

Comment: http://**********.com/skin/frontend/default/*****/images/fb_green.png?whateverrandomthatclearsyorucache